# Not commonly used symbols in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I recently came across some symbols in an Xcode project that I haven't noticed before.

What is

> `@{some_value}` and
>
> `@[some_value]`

Thank you

Comment: I shouldn’t really get -2 for this, you can’t google for such symbols and if you first time notice them in a code and you need a quick answer stackoverflow is the best way. Guys please use your privilege accordingly!

Comment: No Stack Overflow is NOT for asking quick questions. Should I start asking "What is this button in Eclipse? I haven't noticed it before"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `@{key:value}` which represents a dictionary with key and value. `@[some_value]` should be an array. As mentioned in the other answer, check [Objective C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for more details.

From that link an example is,

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"name" : @"some name",
    @"date" : [NSDate date],
    @"processInfo" : [NSProcessInfo processInfo]
};

NSArray *array = @[ @"Hello", NSApp, @42]];
```

Comment: note that NSNumber also supports literals now `@42`

Comment: @vikingosegundo, Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't think about that while writing it. Was focused more on array and dictionary part.

Answer (score 1):

Those are ObjC collection literals. Docs are here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 0):

These are Objective-C 'shortcuts' that allow you to quickly make an NSArray or NSDictionary.

I could say

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"My Object", @"My Second Object", @"My Third Object"];
```

In fact, the @"" notation is the same, in that it allows you to quickly make an NSString.

@{}:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"My Object" : @"My Key", @"My Second Object", @"My Second Key"};
```

Just a quick way for lazy developers to not go through the obviously arduous task of actually typing `[[... alloc] init...]`